# oracle database running but not listening

Tags: database, oracle11g, enterprise

I installed a 11.2020 11g EE Oracle Database

```
SQL> select * from v$version
  2  ;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.2.0      Production
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
```

Initially, everything is good and it listens on port 1521 until I shut down the server.

After restarting, I start the database by running startup

```
SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1603411968 bytes
Fixed Size                  2226912 bytes
Variable Size            1342178592 bytes
Database Buffers          251658240 bytes
Redo Buffers                7348224 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
```

However, the database does not listen and I am unable to connect to the instance.

I can find it in processes but not under the netstat.

```
# ps -ef | grep pmon
ocsgapp  12005     1  0 08:42 ?        00:00:00 ora_pmon_orcl
root     12615 12596  0 09:05 pts/1    00:00:00 grep pmon


# netstat -an | grep 1521
#
```

I haven't changed anything since installation and the content of listener.ora is as the following

```
# cat /home/ocsgapp/app/ocsgapp/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: /home/ocsgapp/app/ocsgapp/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = freeze.dev.unico.com.au)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = /home/ocsgapp/app/ocsgapp
```

I tried to reinstall the whole database and it was listening on 1521 after installation. However, it failed to recover after another shutdown. Does anyone have idea why the db is running but fail to listen on a 1521?

Comment: The database does not listen on port 1521, the listener does.  Is your listener set to start up after a reboot?  If you run `lsnrctl status` at the command line, what is the output?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just tried lsnrctl status and lsnrctl start and I got the following:
./lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 01-MAY-2014 13:04:00

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Message 1053 not found; No message file for product=network, facility=TNSTNS-12541: Message 12541 not found; No message file for product=network, facility=TNS
 TNS-12560: Message 12560 not found; No message file for product=network, facility=TNS
  TNS-00511: Message 511 not found; No message file for product=network, facility=TNS

Comment: Linux Error: 111: Connection refused

Comment: I have made a silly mistake. I forgot to export path before executing the lsnrctl. I can start the listener and be able to connect to the instance from SQL Developer.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The database does not listen for incoming connection requests from clients.  That is the job of a separate process, the listener.  It appears that you haven't set your listener to start up when the server restarts.  If that's the case, you'd need to start the listener

```
./lsnrctl start
```

If you're not sure whether the listener is running

```
./lsnrctl status
```